# How do i compare alphanumeric characters in non sequential order?

Tags: awk

Currently i am using a awk script which compares numbers in non sequential order and prints the difference . It works pretty well for numbers but if i have alphanumeric characters , it doesn't seem to work well

In its current state , apart from simply comparing the numbers it does 2 things additionally :

1. Currently it accounts for the zeros before a number or character and compares the absolute values only ignoring zeros before a number or character
2. Currently  If the same number or character occurs multiple times in both files , it outputs the additional occurance

i just want the script to work well for alphanumeric characters as well as currently it only seem to work well with plain numbers. Can someone please edit the script to have the desired output while also considering the above 2 conditions

**Current script**

```
awk '{k=$0+0} 
       NR==FNR {a[k]++; next} 
       !(k in a && a[k]-->0); 
       END {for(k in a) while(a[k]-->0) print k}' file1 file2
```

**Example below**

cat file1

```
1
01
001
8
2B
12
13C
027B
0027B
```

cat file2

```
1
2
08
12
13C
02B
9
27B
```

**Expected output/result**

```
1
1
2
9
27B
```

**Explanation of expected output**

```
In file1 : "1" , "01" , "001" evaluates to 1 * 3 times
In file 2 : "1" is present only once
Hence "1" is present twice in result ( 3-1 times )
```

```
"2" and "9" are exclusively present in file2 , So obviously both simply form part of output
```

```
In file1 : '027B" , "0027B" evaluates to 27B * 2 times
In file 2 - "27B" is present only once
Hence '27B" is present once in result ( 2 -1 times )
```

**Explanation of matched items** ( ones not forming part of expected output )

```
"8" from file1 ( line 4 )is matched with "08" from file2 ( line 3)
"12" from file1 ( line 6) is matched with "12" from file2 ( line 4)
"13C" from file1 (line 7 ) is matched with "13C" from file2 ( line 5 )
"2B" from file1 ( line 5 ) is matched with "02B" from file2 ( line 6 )
```

Lastly the order of items in expected output should be in ascending order like shown in my above example, lets say if the eg above had 3 in expected output it should read vertically as 1 1 2 3 9 27B

Comment: This is not clear, could you please elaborate why `8` and `13c` is not in expected output of yours?

Comment: File1 has "8" in 4th line and file2 had "08" in 3rd line , absolute value matches . "13C" is present in file1 at 3rd last line and 5th line in file2 so its match hence both are not forming part of expected output

Comment: In file 1 - 1 , 01 ,001 evaluates to 1*3 times , 1 present in file2 once , so it forms part of output twice ( 3-1 times ) . 2 and 9 are exclusively present in file2 . 0027B and 027B evaluates to 27B present twice in file 1 and once in file2 so forming part of output once ( 2 -1 times ). I have provided explanation for other output items too.

Comment: Could you please check once `paste <(awk '{sub(/^0+/,"")} 1' file1) <(awk '{sub(/^0+/,"")} 1' file2) | awk '$1==$2'` and let me know if this is what you are looking? I am still not clear on your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 got this error - zsh: parse error near `)'

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have edited the question with full theoretical explanation of each thing as well . Now i believe there should be no issues in understanding it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to remove leading zeros when forming the key (with a special case for zero values like `0000`):

```
/^0+$/ { k = 0 }
/[^0]/ { k = $0; sub(/^0*/, "", k) }
NR==FNR {a[k]++; next}
!(k in a && a[k]-->0);
END {for(k in a) while(a[k]-->0) print k}

$ awk -f a.awk file1 file2 
2
9
27B
1
1
```

**RE-EDIT**

If you just want the values sorted numerically, pipe into sort:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file1 file2 | sort -n
1
1
2
3
4
5
9
27B
```

To output in the order as found in file2, you can remember the order in another array and then do all the printing in the END block. This version will output the values in the order of file2, with any values only in file1 printed last.

```
/^0+$/ { k = 0 }
/[^0]/ { k = $0; sub(/^0*/, "", k) }
NR==FNR {a[k]++; next}

{ b[FNR] = k }
!(k in a && a[k]--) { a[k] = 1 }
END { 
  for (i=1; i<=FNR; ++i) {
    k = b[i]
    while(a[k]-->0) print k
  }
  for (k in a) {
    while(a[k]-->0) print k
  }
}

$ awk -f a.awk file1 file2 
1
1
2
9
27B
3
4
5
```

Comment: This script doesn't seem to work if a zero is present in front a alphanumeric character .. The first point in my question  - it should compare only the absolute value of a number and that thing should be retained . I have just added 02B in file 2 in question and now its not functioning as intended lists both 2B and 02B in output .it should consider 02B as matched with 2B , like it matches 02 with 2

Comment: See updated version that works for cases like `2B` / `02B`

Comment: thanks it seems working now  lastly is it possible to sort the result in ascending order similar to my question's expected output

Comment: Update with a version that outputs according to the order in file2

Comment: just tested it , the earlier code was working perfectly , it just didn't sorted it well.   The updated one has some derp I beleive ..  Just for testing , i added 3,4,5 at bottom of file 1 and expected it to be present in output , but it was absent from output ...   Please read this for explanation with example  https://del.dog/raw/xynumekasa

Comment: Okay, hopefully I've understood everything this time :-) Try the "re-edit" and let's see.